# How to import MD5MD5 (PHP-Fusion) hashed passwords into Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, passwords, md5

Here [Drupal 6 user password import to Drupal 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6205605/drupal-6-user-password-import-to-drupal-7) is the answer for MD5 hashed passwords.
Not being a programmer myself ;) I'm struggling to see where should I change the code, to work for user passwords not from a previous version of Drupal, but from PHP-Fusion (7.02.01). Could someone help me? :)

Answer (score 1):

The hashing mechanism in Drupal 7 is switchable. As described in the documentation of [password.inc](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--password.inc/7), you can set the `password_inc` (for example in settings.php: `$conf['password_inc'] = '/path/to/alternative/file.inc'`). In that file, you need to implement the 3 functions mentioned in the above link to use the format that is used by PHP-Fusion (which you might be able to re-use to a large part).

That way, you can keep using your old hashes. You could also implement some kind of logic to use the default hashing algorithm's for new passwords and force users to set a new password the next time they log in. That might allow you to drop this part of the code after a year or so when all active users have been updated.

Comment: Mhym. In user_check_password there is `$password = md5($password);`. But as described in my previous mentioned link it doesn't really work for MD5 passwords. It works if you perform the rehash that @hross has described. If I would change that to double MD5, can I also use a similar rehash method? It would be better if Drupal would accept the double MD5 passwords and rehash them to default salted sha512 at users next login. Sorry, I'm really kinda like a blind man here ;) But I'd be really grateful for the help.

Comment: That's what I said. With the method that I explained, you can completely override these functions and do whatever you want. The default implementations will not be used at all. Instead of that file, your own is loaded.

Comment: Yes, I know now which files need to be changed. The problem is that I still don't know how to change the rehash if I would change in user_check_password the single MD5 to double. Cold you help me with that? Tell me what to change in @hross code or what else to change in those three files so that Drupal would accept the double MD5 passwords and rehashed them to it's default hash at the next login.

Comment: you can't rehash at login, only when the password is changed. You could for example prefix all old hashes with something that doesn't show up in the hash like a $. If that $ is there, then you need to use the md5md5 hash compare function, if not, the new one. And the function that hash's new passwords would simply be a duplicate of the default one.

Comment: Mhym... ok, so I've added U$ as the first characters of an old password and I've changed `$password = md5($password);` to `$password = md5(md5($password));`. The rest of the code is the same as in old password.inc, but still I cannot login. What else in password.inc should I change? There is `$hash = _password_crypt('md5', $password, $stored_hash);` later on, but I don't know exactly what the 'md5' part does. And anyway, if I change that to 'md5md5' it still doesn't work.

Comment: When you add  U$ to the stored hash, you also need to add that to the generated hash.

Comment: But the password is substracted at the beginning of user_check_password function `function user_check_password($password, $account) {
  if (substr($account->pass, 0, 2) == 'U$') {` http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--password.inc/function/user_check_password/7

Comment: So where should I add it? Cause I really have no idea. I'm looking at user_check_password and looking and I just can't see what more to change.